# top and htop disagree on memory usage, but swap is being used on GlusterFS server. Can this be improved?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, top, glusterfs, htop

If I run `free -m`, `top` and `htop`, I get different memory uses. The system is also using a small amount of swap. I understand from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/364400/memory-difference-on-top-and-htop) why they are reporting different values (some of the data is considered "discardable" and so included by one system and not included by the other), but not why the system has decided to use the swap? It is a GlusterFS server running the latest version (3.4.3).

**Does anyone know why it is using the swap and not clearing out the "discardable" data from the physical memory and using that instead?**

Is there something I can/should do, or should I just change the monitoring system to not worry about a small amount of swap usage?

**free -m:**

[image: free]

**top:**

[image: top]

**htop:**

[image: htop]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry at all about the small swap usage. It happens that kernel drops some data from memory to swap. You can control the behavior of kernel with the [swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) option:

`echo 60 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

This control is used to define how aggressive the kernel will swap
memory pages.  Higher values will increase agressiveness, lower values
decrease the amount of swap.  A value of 0 instructs the kernel not to
initiate swap until the amount of free and file-backed pages is less
than the high water mark in a zone.
The default value is 60.

You will find more information about the virtual memory subsystem in the [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)

Comment: Hi, thanks, that makes sense. What value would you suggest we should start alerting again on swap usage?

Comment: Swap usage size by itself doesn't mean that much. More important is to know about the pageins/pageouts, this will actually tell you if the system is really swapping/paging. 
High number of pagein/pageout would mean that you are running out of memory and have to push parts of active processes to swap(disk) and then read them again to memory (from disk). 
This is what really impacts your system performance. You can check this out with `vmstat` tool.  On the other hand it's also a problem when you run out of swap space, so it's good 
to monitor the usage to, but I wouldn't worry till 70% ;)

Comment: @LukeCousins I have Nagios alert me whenever ANY swap is used on production servers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation @b13n1u, I'll check out `vmstat`. @Joel E Salas, that's what we have too which was why I was trying to get rid of it, but it seems in this case that it is, in itself now a problem. We'll build some alerts with `vmstat` and set the swap alert a bit higher. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage you are observing is just the same between `free`, `top` and `htop`. Let's calculate it from the `top` view:

```
8171728-(341276+2195864+4061972) / 1024 = 1535
```

which practically matches what you get in `htop`.

Also when you convert `top` values from KB to MB you'll see that the `free` values do match as well.

The swap usage you are panicking over about is probably just some bored daemon swapped out to disk, no worries about that.